# How to increase maximum processing jobs of crystal report in IIS7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached.

My all code works fine but after some time it shows the error that Crystal Report maximum processing jobs limit exceeded. How i can increase this to unlimited or a greater number of processing limit? so that it will not show this error again and again. It works fine on my system(local) but when i deploy this application on server then this error will arise after some time. any body can help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your code?

Ensure you are doing:

```
ReportDocument.Close();
ReportDocument.Dispose();
```

Comment: buddy i used different method to do this. here is the URL        http://forums.asp.net/p/984650/1268025.aspx

Comment: if your solution is different you can post an answer yourself. although i looked at that link and it's the same as my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the registry entry under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Business Objects[Version#]\Report Application Server\InProcServer\PrintJobLimit.  Be careful when changing it on the server as this determines the amount of resources that can be used.  I would suggest checking your code to make sure you are disposing the report objects properly as you should not need to increase the limit unless you have a large number of concurrent users generating reports.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use try..catch..finally. It helps on disposing:

```
try

    {
        //your code
    }

catch (Exception ex)

    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

finally

    {
        ReportDocument.Close();
        ReportDocument.Dispose();
    }
```

I hope it helps you.